# Maximum transfer of energy to the pan

Tags: efficiency

On an induction cook-top, does it make a difference in the efficiency of the pan that is getting heated if the pan has more or less a concentration of like stainless steel?  Is efficiency less if the pan has a lower amount of stainless steel on the bottom vs. all stainless steel?  Will the pan heat faster, cook hotter?  Or will the pan with less stainless steel heat and cook at the same rate?

Answer (score 1):

Define efficiency.
Efficiency of energy use, or cooking?

A heavy-based pan will maintain a more even temperature, which improves cooking efficiency, but takes more energy to heat initially & 'wastes' energy cooling down afterwards, so is less efficient on power.